# Display name of user in VF page, given a user ID stored on a related object

Tags: visualforce

I have a custom object (Grievance_Note__c) that stores a CreatedById for each note. I want to display the name of the user who created the note. Right now the VF page is displaying the User ID and I can't figure out how to get the user's first and last name from the ID. Do I have to define a variable and add a separate SOQL query to the controller to be able to display that on the page?

**MrcCaseList.vfp**:

```
<apex:page standardController="Grievance__c" extensions="MrcCaseListController" sidebar="false">
        <apex:repeat value="{!notes}" var="n">
            <apex:outputText value="{!n.Note__c}" style="width: 100%; display: block; padding:10px 0;border-top:1px solid gray;" />
            <div style="width: 100%; display: flex; justify-content:space-between; padding: 10px 0;">
                <div style="display: flex; flex-direction: column;">
                    <apex:outputText value="{0,date,MM/dd/yyyy}" style="font-weight: bold;">Contact Date: <apex:param value="{!n.Contact_Date__c}" /> </apex:outputText>
                    <apex:outputText value="{!n.Contact_Type__c}" style="" />
                </div>
                <apex:outputText value="{!n.CreatedById}" style="font-weight: bold; padding-right: 20px;" />
                <apex:outputText style="">
                    <apex:outputLink value="/{!n.id}" target="_blank">
                        <apex:outputText value="{0,date,MM/dd/yyyy h:mm a}">
                            <apex:param value="{!n.Note_Created_Date_Time__c}" />
                        </apex:outputText>
                    </apex:outputLink>
                </apex:outputText>
            </div>
        </apex:repeat>
</apex:page>
```

**MrcCaseListController.apxc**:

```
public with sharing class MrcCaseListController {

    private final Grievance__c mrcCase;

    public MrcCaseListController(ApexPages.StandardController stdController) {
        this.mrcCase = (Grievance__c)stdController.getRecord();
    }

    public List<Grievance_Note__c> getNotes() {
        return [
            SELECT  Id,
                    Note__c,
                    Note_Created_Date_Time__c,
                    Contact_Date__c,
                    Grievance__c,
                    Contact_Type__c,
                    CreatedById,
                    LastModifiedById
            FROM    Grievance_Note__c
            WHERE   Grievance__c = :mrcCase.id
            ORDER   BY Note_Created_Date_Time__c
        ];
    }
}
```

Comment: You can utilize `CreatedBy.Name` and that will give you the Name of the User.

Comment: @JayantDas where do I get that though? There is no field called CreatedBy on the Grievance_Note__c object -- just a field called CreatedById which is a lookup to the User object and stores an ID. I can't just substitute CreatedBy.Name into my VF page because there isn't a field by that name available to display. Can you give more detail?

Comment: I added that as an answer with details. `CreatedById` is a reference to `User` object and that you can always get the User details using `CreatedBy.fieldNameOnUser`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can add `CreatedBy.Name` in your SOQL and then utilize the same on your VF page.

So you query would look like:

```
return [
        SELECT  Id,
                CreatedBy.Name,
                ...
    ];
```

And then on your VF page, you render it using as:

```
<apex:outputText value="{!n.CreatedBy.Name}" style="font-weight: bold; padding-right: 20px;" />
```

Comment: ah, got it now, thank you! worked perfectly!